# ec2 and cloudwatch loggroups connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

How do I check which log groups are attached to which ec2 instance, I checked in
CloudWatch Logs>Log groups>Tags but that is empty, is there any way to check which log groups are associated with which ec2 instance?

Out of these 158 log groups how do I find which are associated with this ec2 instance
**cbax-quick-apply-prod**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you get its instance id (not name) and search your log groups using the id?

Comment: I searched using instance id in log groups still it gets no results @Marcin

Comment: I guess these are custom logs? If so, you have to check how these logs are generated and how instance is identified in these logs.

Comment: These are cloudwatch logs and these are generated through code deployment, load balancer and autoscaling , but still from there I could not find any connection @Marcin